# How to correctly use multi line subscripts

Tags: subscripts

So, the problem is simple:

```
$\min_{\begin{array}{c}
                              x\\ 
                               y
                             \end{array}}f$
```

how to adjust the space between the two subscripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `stackengine` stack, the vertical gap distances can be set.  Differing horizontal alignments can also be set (default centered), if the stacking elements are of different width.

Furthermore, unlike using an `array`, the depth of the subscript is compatible with `\min_x` as shown in the last item.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\
$\min_{\stackunder[6pt]{\scriptstyle x}{\scriptstyle y}}f\quad
\min_{\stackunder[2pt]{\scriptstyle x}{\scriptstyle y}}f\quad
\min_x
$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'd say that *ehsanks* now deleted comment about `\substack` is the most traditional. It only require `amsmath` and is shorter to write

```
\[
    min_{\substack{i,j \\ j<i }} ....
\]
```